# Raffle with X participants. Same Raffle is repeated Y times. Odds of winning exactly/at least 1, 2, 3... times?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There's a weekly raffle with 20 participants. It will last for 10 weeks.

Every participant has the same probability of winning on any given week $\left(\frac1{20} \right)$.

I know that the probability of me winning $0$ times is $\left(19\frac1{20} \right)^{10} = 59.9\%$, which means I have a $40.1\%$ chance of winning at least once, right?

But how can I calculate the following probability:

- Me winning exactly N times.
- Me winning at least N times.

Thanks,

Comment: The question appears to confuse odds with probability.

Comment: Thanks, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the chance of winning at least once is about $40.1\%$. To calculate the probability to win exactly N times in $M$ weeks you have to use the binomial distribution.

$$P(X=N)=\binom{M}{N}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{20} \right)^{N}\cdot \left(\frac{19}{20} \right)^{M-N}$$

Similar for the probability to win at least $N$ times in $M$ weeks is

$$P(X\geq N)=\sum_{k=N}^{M}\binom{M}{k}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{20} \right)^{k}\cdot \left(\frac{19}{20} \right)^{M-k}$$

Comment: Thanks! Should I use the same formula whether the raffle lasts for 10 weeks or more (or less)? What I mean is, in the binomial distribution formula, I don't understand in which part the result is being affected by the number of weeks the raffle will run for. Edit: it should be 10 choose N for 10 weeks right? The answer above states 20 choose N.

Comment: @gerpez That´s true. The answer is referring to 20 weeks. I will make an edit to point it out.